# Changing text based on click bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code here which is implemented using bootstrap. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="map-images">
            <img src="images/map/level0.png" title="image 1" alt="Ground floor" id="image1" class="image-toggle"/>
            <img src="images/map/level1.png" title="image 2" alt="floor 1" id="image2" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
            <img src="images/map/level2.png" title="image 3" alt="floor 2" id="image3" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
            <img src="images/map/level3.png" title="image 4" alt="floor 3" id="image4" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image1" data-link="first">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" href="#lvl0-overview"> Ground Floor
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image2" data-link="second">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" href="#lvl1-overview"> Floor 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image3" data-link="third">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" href="#lvl2-overview"> Floor 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image4" data-link="fourth">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" href="#lvl3-overview"> Floor 3
            </label>
        </div>
```

This is the JavaScript for the code above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.image-toggler').click(function(){
        $('.image-toggle').hide();
        $($(this).attr('data-image-id')).show();
    });
</script>
```

Which basically what it does is, change the picture shown based on the click of the buttons in order to select the floor and allow the user to see the floor map.
What I want is to add an onclick option, which will spawn a floor description underneath the buttons.

Something like this

```
-------------
| Floor      |
| overview   |  <-image swapping here based on button click
|            |
|            |
-------------
button1 button2 button3

--------------
| floor       |
| description | <-Change divs based on the current floor.
|             |
|             |
--------------
```

What more should I add to my code? I have tried to implement it using simple CSS, implementing the advice found on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kqK3A/) post. So I've added an `href` tag to every `<input>` element, linking to divs later on. But, I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use the exact same method that you have used to display the image?

Comment: @Turnip You cant do that because you need a picture ID to feed to the Jscript, but you cant have 2 ids, for 1 picture. I think, at least...

Comment: What I meant was to add another data attribute to your labels: `data-description-id` maybe - this would hold the ID of the description element that you wish to show. Then use this ID in the same way as you have done to hide / show the images.

Comment: That was it. I'm kinda of a newbie in HTML and bootstrap so i was trying this approach. but putting that id in the wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no css is prevent the images to be visible

(e.g. some `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`)

Check this implementation (width event delegation):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.image-toggler', function() {
  $('.image-toggle').hide();  
  $($(this).attr('data-image-id')).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-images">
            <img src="images/map/level0.png" title="image 1" alt="Ground floor" id="image1" class="image-toggle"/>
            <img src="images/map/level1.png" title="image 2" alt="floor 1" id="image2" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
            <img src="images/map/level2.png" title="image 3" alt="floor 2" id="image3" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
            <img src="images/map/level3.png" title="image 4" alt="floor 3" id="image4" class="image-toggle" style="display:none;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image1" data-link="first">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" href="#lvl0-overview"> Ground Floor
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image2" data-link="second">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" href="#lvl1-overview"> Floor 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image3" data-link="third">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" href="#lvl2-overview"> Floor 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary image-toggler" data-image-id="#image4" data-link="fourth">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" href="#lvl3-overview"> Floor 3
            </label>
        </div>
```